# How to map MVC models with Inheritance present

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I am trying to make use of inheritance within my MVC models.
There are 2 places in the project where a user can register damage to some equipment.
When it is being moved or just during a stock count.
I have:
Transport
Transport Details

StockCheck
StockCheckDetails

The Details models are both a collection of some type of object.
A single damage record can be made against a single Detail item.
I have created an abstract Damage model where details of the Damage can be recorded.

So I then have 2 models that inherit from Damage
TransportDetailDamage and StockDetailDamage

My TransportDetail record can then have either 0 or 1 TransportDetailDamage record.
A StockCheckDetail record can also either have 0 or 1 StockDetailDamage record.

My current models are (just transport and most props removed for brevity):

```
public class TransportDetail {
    public int TransportDetailID { get; set; }

    public int TransportID { get; set; }
    public Transport Transport { get; set; }

    public TransportDamage TransportDamage { get; set; }
}
public abstract class Damage {
    public int DamageID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class TransportDamage : Damage {
    public TransportDetail TransportDetail { get; set; }
}
```

I keep getting alsorts of errors from principal ends to invalid keys defined.
I would also very much like to be able to define the field names using the Fluent API so I don't end up with the likes of TransportDamage_DamageID etc

EDIT:
OK I have added some Fluent API that seems to allow the model to work properly but it does not seem totally correct, a TransportDetail certainly can have Optional TransportDamage but the TransportDamage Requires a TransportDetail to exist....
The .Map does cover the horrible auto-field names in the database through :)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TransportDetail>()
  .HasOptional(x=>x.TransportDamage)
  .WithOptionalPrincipal(x=>x.TransportDetail)
  .Map(t=>t.MapKey("TransportDetailID"));
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

May be this problem is due to property definition of class. You have defined a property of type "TransportDamage" in TransportDetail class and a property of type "TransportDetail" in TransportDamage class.

Comment: Yea as far as I know that is how to provide navigation between the two entities?